# Plain TableView Separator not Removing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a Plain `UITableView` & I want to hide Separator. For hiding it, I tried with below properties:

I also set this in `viewDidLoad`.

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

but still separator in there in `UITableView`. How can I remove it?

Comment: Show the tableView screen shot

Comment: it is not possible, please add your tableview screen shot

Comment: @ravi.p i don't know whats's going wrong, when i programatically change Separator Colour or Separator Starting Point, it will not affect when i run it in Simulator or device.

Comment: add your code in any cloud storage lat me check it cause as per your current property of tableview it will be not showing but in your screen shot is showing so if possible share your code

Comment: @Pankil try to delete and add new tableview

Answer (score 0):

For Objective C

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

For Swift

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
```

Comment: Have you read the question?, OP already setting `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` as `separatorStyle`

Comment: Use the setter method as mentioned above

Comment: Share Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Hope it will help you.

```
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
    }
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, cell.bounds.size.width);
    if([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

please see the screenshot.Change separator from **Singleline** in properties to **None**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUpRz.png)

Comment: did you see my uploaded screenshots?